# Enable item scheduling on a publishing library via SharePoint .NET client API

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, csom

**Does anybody know how to enable item scheduling on a publishing library via code (.NET Client API)?**

This can be done via the Settings UI for the library in Manage Item Scheduling.  However, I can't find a way to enable this using the .NET Client API.  It must not be as simple as just setting a property on the List object like EnableModeration = true or EnableVersioning = true.  I can't use the Server-Side API because I'm in Office 365 Sharepoint.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the following post.
To enable Item scheduling, events must be enabled in the library.
http://labofsudip.blogspot.co.uk/2015/08/enable-item-scheduling-in-library-using.html